I transferred out 1500usd into a coin base account and the money seemed to have just disappeared. it said the transfer went through but i got nothing
having some issues with transfers, sending and receiving coins. The coin i held spiked and i tried to send out 1500 usd. it said the transfer went through but no money was sent over and it disappeared out of my phantom account
please help!! thank you

Do you have a transaction / signature? Can you see it in Phantom?
One possible issue can be the account for USDC did not exist in Coinbase and needed to be funded.
In the future - always send a test amount of $1 or so just to ensure the pipes are working first before sending big amounts.

I have got a transaction on both coin base and phantom. That may be a possibility but i was trading it into solana so that shouldn't have been as issue. yeah i am going to have to send some money to see what happens next time. It also says on my phantom transactions that there was an app interaction with unknown under it but still with a tick. i am very confused. should have the money bounced back? why didn't it pop up in coin base even though it says received

The funds do not bounce. They get lost
